# Why originated process started as zombie in Qt-app. Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, process, zombie-process

I am writing a small application on linux using qt creator.
When i start my application i want it to execute a shell command. I`m using QProcess for it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

    {
        MyApplication a(argc, argv);

        QProcess mapProc(&a);

        QString command;
        QStringList args;

        command = "java";
        args << "-jar" << "/home/$USER/MapServer/map.jar" << "localhost" << "9797" << "12123";

        mapProc.start(command, args);

        bool flag  = mapProc.waitForStarted();
        QProcess::ProcessState state = mapProc.state();

        qDebug() << mapProc.errorString();
        qDebug() << mapProc.pid();


    /*/////////////////
    some code
    /////////////////*/

        return a.exec();
    }
```

but when my application started, process "mapProc" becomes a zombie. Why? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with any simple external program, or just with this map.jar? Also, have you messed with SIGCHILD?

Comment: i solved it. command $USER doesnt work as parameter. it need full path as const string: "/home/cupuyc/MapServer/map.jar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$USER` will not really work like that with `QProcess`. You will need to invoke the command through `/bin/sh -c "mycmd"` or even better if you just do it the proper Qt way as indicated below.

Try using [QStandardPaths](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#locate), so write this:

```
QString homeLocation =
    QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
args << "-jar" << QString(homeLocation.first() + "/MapServer/map.jar")
     << "localhost" << "9797" << "12123";
```

instead of this:

```
args << "-jar" << "/home/$USER/MapServer/map.jar"
     << "localhost" << "9797" << "12123";
```